# maven having problem recognising JDK.Environmental variable attached

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot find JDK_HOME directory with $JDK_HOME/bin/javap and$JDK_HOME/bin/javah utilities, please check JDK_HOME environment variable
    at com.alexkasko.maven.jniheaders.Utils.jdkHome (Utils.java:45)
    at com.alexkasko.maven.jniheaders.JavahMojo.execute (JavahMojo.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
```

Here is my configuration

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1
Maven home: /Applications/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_301, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: Seems like JDK is not in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` directory. Can you verify if that is the root directory of `jdk`? That is, check if you have `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

Comment: @Imesha Sudasingha : Java exist in the class Path you suggested

Comment: Do you have a `javap` or `javah` file within the same `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin` directory?

Comment: Hi @ImeshaSudasingha It looks like it was looking for JDK path and not java Path. I updated that and it worked. Thanks for guiding me

Comment: The java what you mentioned might be a JVM (runtime) but not a JDK which is necessary.

Comment: The `jni-headers-maven-plugin` writes [some debug log](https://github.com/alexkasko/jni-headers-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alexkasko/maven/jniheaders/Utils.java#L32). Maybe `mvn -X` will give you some hints...?